# How to sum a range based on a true/false formula referencing another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with the below tabs.
 - Tracking (REV)
 - Resource Data

At the beginning of the REV Spreadsheet I have Ref.# that are the same across each sheet, but I do not bring across all the columns from the Resource Data tab into the REV tab.  However for the columns I do bring across, this means that if I sort data, the formula's are always going to be looking for the unique Ref ID before anything else.

What I am trying to do...
At the bottom of the REV sheet I am trying to sum the monthly columns if when looking up the reference ID on the Resource Data sheet, it runs a true/false against each row by looking at the project name and matching that to a referenced cell with the project name on the REV tab.

The workaround for the time being is to add the Project Name column into the REV spreadsheet, but then I need to go change all my vba code for the generation of these complex workbooks.

I have tried using a SUMIF in combination with INDEX MATCH.

`=SUMIF(Tracking_REV[Ref.
'#],INDEX(ResourceData,MATCH('Tracking (REV)'!A4,ResourceData[Ref.
'#],0),10),Tracking_REV[Feb-19
(Actual)
Calendar])`

I'm expecting to be able to sum the range as descriped above, without having to add a column into the sheet.

[Resource Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbl2F.png)
[Tracking (REV) Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX1qy.png)

Comment: What does the Function Return ? Did you try stepping through it ?

Comment: It returns 0.  Stepping through it didn't help me at all, I couldn't make heads or tails of it. :(

Comment: So much possible through formula, probably also your problem, but it's just not clear. Maybe add some simple sample data with expected output.

Comment: The empty sheets don't help that much. Some sample data with expected output would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the criteria for you to look up the sales are the reference number and project name. You cannot simply look up the figure using the reference number.

If that's the case you properly need to show Project Name on the REV sheet.

I am not sure how adding a column would impact your VBA. If you can specify this then I may be able to give you a better answer.

For now my suggestion would be adding the Project Name as a new column at the end of your REV report which may not have impact on your pre-written VBA code.

Alternatively replace a current column on your REV sheet which is not important with Project Name so it dose not change the size of your report which might not affect your VBA.

If not please give more details regarding your VBA code.

Comment: Thank you.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but I feared that might be the case.  I'll just have to make the changes to the vba scripts :(.